# Warning: You are calling ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has already been passed to createRoot() before

Tags: reactjs

Hola tengo el siguiente error

```
Warning: You are calling ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has already been passed to createRoot() before. Instead, call root.render() on the existing root instead if you want to update it.
```

En el siguiente codigo:

```
 ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
      <HouseContextProvider>
        <Router>
          <Wrapper>
            <React.StrictMode>
              <Routes>
                <Route path="*" element={<App />} />
              </Routes>
            </React.StrictMode>
          </Wrapper>
        </Router>
      </HouseContextProvider>
```

Estuve investigando como solucionarlo e intente lo siguiente

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <HouseContextProvider>
    <Router>
      <Wrapper>
        <React.StrictMode>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="*" element={<App />} />
          </Routes>
        </React.StrictMode>
      </Wrapper>
    </Router>
  </HouseContextProvider>
);
```

Pero esta solución no funciono para mi , el error persiste. Alguna otra solución para este `warning`?

Comment: no estas usando createRoot() sobre algun elemento donde ya hayas pasado createRoot(elemento)? porque en cuanto al codigo no veo nada malo.

Comment: No, es el unico lugar donde lo estoy usando